# Merge and synonymize [temporary-table], [temp-table] and [temp-tables] into [temporary-tables]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Merge and synonymize [temporary-table](/questions/tagged/temporary-table) (2), [temp-table](/questions/tagged/temp-table) (3) and [temp-tables](/questions/tagged/temp-tables) (3) into [temporary-tables](/questions/tagged/temporary-tables) (37).

Comment: Where did you get these numbers from next to each tag? I'm seeing 19, 30, 8, and 253.

Comment: @animuson: To the right, "questions tagged".